# C fopen() - Possible issue with absolute path

Tags: c, windows, path, fopen

I'm currently using Code::Blocks 13.12 (compiler: GNU GCC) under Windows 10.

I'm trying to open a file and load its content, but fopen gives me troubles. The 'input.txt' exists in the same directory as my executable. I've already checked the permissions.

Function for getting the path:

```
char* getFileName()                        
{         
    char *fileName; /* the path of the .txt file */
    char path[MAX_PATH];

   /* get the path of the executable */
   GetModuleFileName(NULL, path, MAX_PATH);
   /* remove the name of the executable from the path */
   PathRemoveFileSpec(path);
   /* check case where path is directory root */
   if(PathIsRoot(path))
       strcat(path, "\\*");

   /* add the name of the .txt file to the path */
   strcat(path, "\\input.txt");
   /* not sure if needed */
   path[strlen(path)] = '\0';
   fileName = strdup((char *) path);

   return fileName;
}
```

Function for loading the contents of the file:

```
bool loadDict(char *fileName)
{
    FILE *fp; /* file stream */
    char line[LINE_SIZE]; /* each line of the file */
    // other variables

    /* try to open file for reading */
    if((fp = fopen(fileName, "r")) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Could not open the file '%s' to read\n", fileName);
        return false;
    }

    // stuff done

    /* file is no longer needed, close it */
   if(fclose(fp))
   {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Could not close the file '%s' to read\n", fileName);
        return false;
   }
   return true; /* in case no problem has occured */
}
```

Main:

```
int main()
{
    char *fileName;

    fileName = getFileName();
   /* try to load the dictionary into memory */
   if(!loadDict(fileName))
   {
       fprintf(stderr, "Error: The dictionary could be not loaded into memory.\nProgram terminating...\n");
       return 1;
   }

    // other stuff
    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting both errors (could not open the file, could not load). I've already tried replacing '\' with '/' or using double slashes without success.

```
 FILE *fp = fopen("path\\input.txt", "r");
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does your path contain any spaces or non-ASCII symbols? This could be an issue

Comment: Nope, the path consists only of latin letters.

Comment: Stop using tools, that default to MBCS (ANSI) character encoding. For the record: It is the year 2016.

Comment: Do not modify your question so that the answer(s) become meaningless.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Ok, sorry.

Comment: In your question you say the file is in the parent directory of the directory containing the executable, but your code reads the file from the *same* directory as contains the executable.  Is that your problem?  (If not, you should edit the question to clarify it.)  Also, the code that says "check case where path is directory root" makes no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're returning the address of a local variable in `getFileName`, which results in *undefined behavior*. 
This is a common pitfall in C.

You need to either: 
A) Allocate the string on the heap (using e.g. `malloc`) and return it.
B) Have `getFileName` take a pointer to a caller-allocated buffer which it then populates.

Also, when debugging problems like this, don't just assume everything is working. Use `printf` to see what the value of `filename` is before you try to `fopen` it.

Comment: "Doesn't work" means nothing, sorry. You need to explain exactly what doesn't work. Print out fileName immediately before the call to fopen.

Comment: `printf` style debugging is not the recommended way to debug code. It is inappropriate, as running code will inevitably have side effects. A debugger should be used instead.

Comment: First of all, thanks for answering. Secondly, exactly before fopen 'fileName' is 'C:\Users\etc\etc\input.txt'. I've tried replacing '\' with '/' again. Should I try with double slash?

Comment: @M.Demo: Seems like you're trying to open a file, for which you are lacking access rights.

Comment: @IInspectable No, I've already checked the permissions and the file is set to 'everyone full control'.

Comment: @M.Demo: If an answer does not solve your problem, you should not accept it. From your comments it appears as though this answer doesn't solve your issue.

Comment: @IInspectable Oh, sorry. I should have updated my post. For some odd reason, 'C:\Users\etc\etc\input' works while 'C:\Users\etc\etc\input.txt' does not. But the above answer helped me with the most important bug, that's why I accepted it.

Answer (score 1):

Your array `path` is a local variable whose scope is limited to function `getFileName`. Don't return its address .

Instead pass it from the calling function.